# blue screen of death ntoskrnl.exe DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Tags: windows-10, drivers, hardware-failure, crash, bluescreenview

i was restarting the computer when i got a  blue screen of death

i used BlueScreenView to get this :

==================================================

```
Dump File         : 102217-35234-01.dmp

Crash Time        : 10/22/2017 00:03:19

Bug Check String  : DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

Bug Check Code    : 0x0000009f

Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000004

Parameter 2       : 00000000`0000012c

Parameter 3       : ffffd609`774f1440

Parameter 4       : ffffb98c`2903f810

Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe

Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+163960

File Description  : NT Kernel & System

Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

Company           : Microsoft Corporation

File Version      : 10.0.16299.19 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

Processor         : x64

Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+163960

Stack Address 1   : 

Stack Address 2   : 

Stack Address 3   : 

Computer Name     : 

Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\102217-35234-01.dmp

Processors Count  : 4

Major Version     : 15

Minor Version     : 16299

Dump File Size    : 1,865,758

Dump File Time    : 10/22/2017 09:16:34
```

==================================================

can someone tell me why this happened ?

Comment: use [Windbg to debug the crash](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) (not this BlueScreenview): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x9f--driver-power-state-failure

Comment: Are you by chance using Node in any development efforts? I just got this same issue after the Creators update. I opened up my WinDbg to see what was at fault and found Node.exe referenced

Comment: 0x0000009f is always caused by a faulty driver. All cases I saw were Intel NIC or graphics driver.

Answer (score 1):

0x0000009f is always caused by a faulty driver. All cases I saw were Intel NIC or graphics driver.
You can workaround it by disabling power management in the driver properties: Device Management > select device and right-click - Properties > Power management tab > uncheck checkboxes